# Car class problem- break and acceleration functions?

Tags: python, class

I need to code an accelerate function, accelerating speed by 5 mph and a brake function decelerating speed by 5 mph for a car class with the following logic:

-when braked, speed must be >= 0. if speed < 0 then reset to 0 and display error

-when accelerated, speed be <= 130. if speed > 130 then reset to 130 and display error

I think I've gotten so far as the parameters but not sure how to proceed with the functions themselves.

Tester program:

```
from Car import *
def main():
    my_car = Car("2008", "Honda Accord")
    print(f"my_car after instantiating: {my_car}")

    my_car.setSpeed(116)
    print(f"my_car after my_car.setSpeed(116): {my_car}")

    my_car.setSpeed(136)
    print(f"my_car after my_car.setSpeed(136): {my_car}")
    
    print ("*** car is accelerating ***")
    for i in range(4):
        my_car.accelerate()
        print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

    my_car.setSpeed(11)
    print(f"my_car after my_car.setSpeed(11): {my_car}")
  
    print ("*** car is braking ***")
    for i in range(3):
        my_car.brake()
        print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

    print(f"my_car at program end: {my_car}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the class:

```
class Car:
    __make_model = ""
    __year = ""
    __speed = 0
        
    def __init__(self, param_year, param_make_model):
        self.__make_model = param_make_model
        self.__year = param_year
        self.__speed = 0

    def setMake_model(self, param_make_model):
        self.__make_model = param_make_model

    def getMake_model(self):
        return self.__make_model

    def setYear(self, param_year):
        self.__year = make

    def getYear(self):
        return self.__year
    
    def setSpeed(self, inp_speed):
        if inp_speed < 0 or inp_speed > 130:
            print(f"Speed cannot be {inp_speed} mph.",
                  "Speed be must be 0-130 mph")
        else:
            self.__speed = inp_speed

    def getSpeed(self):
        return self.__speed
  
    def __str__(self):
        ret_val = f"Year : {self.__year}"
        ret_val += f", Make and Model : {self.__make_model}"
        ret_val += f", Speed : {self.__speed}"
        return ret_val
```

I don't know how to proceed adding this to the class, specifically in getting the class to reset to the limit I want to set.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to skin this cat, but here is an option:

```
class Car:
    __make_model = ""
    __year = ""
    __speed = 0
        
    def __init__(self, param_year, param_make_model):
        self.__make_model = param_make_model
        self.__year = param_year
        self.__speed = 0

    def setMake_model(self, param_make_model):
        self.__make_model = param_make_model

    def getMake_model(self):
        return self.__make_model

    def setYear(self, param_year):
        self.__year = make

    def getYear(self):
        return self.__year
    
    def setSpeed(self, inp_speed):
        if inp_speed < 0 or inp_speed > 130:
            print(f"Speed cannot be {inp_speed} mph.",
                  "Speed be must be 0-130 mph")
        else:
            self.__speed = inp_speed

    def getSpeed(self):
        return self.__speed
    
    def accelerate(self):
        if self.__speed <= 125:
            self.__speed += 5
        else:
            print("error max speed is 130")
            self.__speed = 130
            
    def brake(self):
        if self.__speed >= 5:
            self.__speed -= 5
        else:
            print("error reseting to 0")
            self.__speed = 0
  
    def __str__(self):
        ret_val = f"Year : {self.__year}"
        ret_val += f", Make and Model : {self.__make_model}"
        ret_val += f", Speed : {self.__speed}"
        return ret_val
```